# Access all function arguments in R

Tags: r

I've a function f() that has some named parameters. It calls a function g() and I want to pass all f's parameters to it. Is this possible?

Using ... just covers the extra arguments:

```
f=function(a,callback,b,c,d,...){
  z=a-b
  callback(z,...) 
  }

g=function(z,...){
  print(list(...))    #Only shows $e
  print(z)    #-1
  print(a,b,c,d)  #'a' not found   
}

f(1,g,2,3,d=4,e=5);
```

I thought formals() was the answer, but it just seems to be argument names, not their values!

```
f=function(a,callback,b,c,d,...){
  z=a-b
  callback(z,formals()) 
  }

g=function(z,...){
  args=list(...)[[1]]
  print(args$a) #(no output)
  print(class(args$a))  #"name"
}

f(1,g,2,3,d=4,e=5);
```

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at the code for `lm` and `glm` to see how this is done.

Comment: @HongOoi Thanks; it is done with match.call (i.e. just like Anton's answer), though IIUC it chooses to only pass on certain args, not all of them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well, something like this is certainly possible. You should just figure our for yourself in which frame / point you'd like to evaluate the arguments of f which are then forwarded to g.

The typical procedure consists of match.call() call inside f to actually record the call expression which f was called with, then changing the call expression as it should be convenient for you (e.g. filtering out unnecessary args, adding new, etc.) and then evaluation of the new call expression via eval() call. So, something like this should (almost) work:

```
f <- function(a, callback, b, c, d, ...) {
  # Grab the "f" call expression
  fcall <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)

  # Construct the new call expression
  fcall[[1]] <- callback
  # Filter out / add new args
  fcall$callback <- NULL
  fcall$z <- z

  # Do the call
  eval(fcall, parent.frame())
}
```

Comment: Or you could just pass along the extra args yourself. Much much easier to understand.

Comment: @hadley Yes, but harder to maintain as the argument list changes. After considering all the choices, in my actual code I went for a named list argument that contains all the other arguments. I.e. _Introduce Parameter Object_ in Refactoring jargon. So I'm just passing one argument to f() and that same argument is given to g().

Comment: Also worth noting that `sys.call` is similar to `match.call` but doesn’t substitute argument names: With `f(1, callback = list)`, the above would return `list(a = 1)` while a version with `sys.call` would return `list(1)`.

Comment: So the best way to capture all passed arguments as faithfully as possible is: `function(a,b, ...) { call <- sys.call(); call[[1]] <- as.name('list'); args <- eval.parent(call)) }`